# Question about Inkscape (icons with solid white background with an alpha image)

Tags: inkscape, logo, transparency

EDIT:
Hello, yes, I am trying to get transparent icons on a solid white background.
Also, the second link is not broken. It needs html code to display it correctly.
Here is a screen shot of what it does when I change background color using html.
I can get it using Pixlr, but the image quality suffers.

[[image: transparent icons with solid background]

---

I have looked high and low but everything online deals with a transparent background. I have managed to do that using Inkscape, but what I need is a solid white background with an alpha image.

PNG with a transparent alpha background

I have also managed to make the image itself transparent with a solid background using Pixlr. But, the quality is just horrible. Can I achieve the below using Inkscape or similar without compromising on image sharpness?

[PNG with transparent background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08mqA.png)

[PNG with transparent icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trEYp.png)

The second will show up as blank image unless it is embedded with background color in html.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Unfortunately, I am not sure that I understand what exactly you want to achieve and what your problem is. Do you want black icons on a transparent background (your first example) or transparent icons on a white background? Please [edit] your question to clarify what you need (and fix that broken image link).

Comment: Probably you want to invert the alpha channel in your image?

Comment: That is what I did using Pixlr. But I can't seem to do the same in Inkscape?

Comment: I'm also not clear what you are actually trying to accomplish. What part are you struggling with?

Comment: @DA01 yes, I know it's a odd requirement. the aim here is to use one png file with a few icons as src for img tag in my html code. when I change the background color only the icons should change color as seen in the screenshots above. Sorry to repeat myself; I am able to do this in pixlr (bad quality) but not in inkscape.

Comment: I see, so you want to create solid white images where the drawing is 'punched out' of the white so background color shows through?

Answer (score 2):

So you are drawing your icons in Inkscape? Try this:

- If you are using lines of some width, use the "Path > Stroke to path" command to convert them into filled paths without a stroke.
- If you are using text, use the "Object > Ungroup" command to convert each text object into individual filled paths.
- If you are using filled paths, leave them unchanged but check that they don't have a stroke.
- Select all resulting paths.
- Use the "Path > Union" command to merge them into one filled path.
- Draw a rectangle of the desired icon's size over the merged path.
- Select both the rectangle and the merged path.
- Use the "Path > Exclusion" command to subtract the path from the rectangle.
- Adjust the color of the resulting object.
- Export to PNG.

Comment: I've already tried this Goblin. No dice. Also, the original icons were designed in AI, just so you know. I do import .ai and use the export to png option.

Comment: @kFMIF, what's the result? I think any vector graphics imported to Inkscape can be ungrouped and converted to paths.

Answer (score 0):

Another option. I don't know Pixlr, but since you are able to save PNG with alpha, it appears to be a decent image editor.

- Export the icon from AI or Inkscape to PNG, as you have done previously, but with a very large image size (e.g. 10 times larger than needed)
- Open it in Pixlr, add solid background and make the coloured areas transparent
- Resize (resample) the image to the required size (use the best quality settings)

Hopefully the alpha channel gets smoothed during resize and you will get the required good image quality.